# After adding seconds to timestamp, not getting expected result from unix timestamp to datetime conversion

Tags: python, datetime, unix-timestamp, date-conversion

I am writing a program that deals with unix timestamps and dates.
I have a date (`2014-10-26 00:00:00`), convert it to its timestamp and add 60 times 60 times 24 seconds (the number of seconds in one day).

So the resulting timestamp's date should be `2014-10-27 00:00:00`. It isn't, it's
`2014-10-26 23:00:00`. This irritates me, I can't figure out the logic behind that.
I wrote a python script that adds 3600 seconds to the initial date in a loop.

The output is:

```
1414274400 2014-10-26 00:00:00
1414278000 2014-10-26 01:00:00
1414281600 2014-10-26 02:00:00
1414285200 2014-10-26 02:00:00    NOTE: 02:00:00 is doubled!
1414288800 2014-10-26 03:00:00
1414292400 2014-10-26 04:00:00
1414296000 2014-10-26 05:00:00
...
           2014-10-26 23:00:00
```

What is going on here? Can someone explain that to me?

My naive conversion routine:

```
def ts2date(ts):
    return(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts))
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time

Comment: @ThierryLathuille: 2014-10-26 was not the the first Sunday of November that year.

Comment: @martineau I just learned it thanks to your comment: the dates are not the same in the USA and in Europe. In Europe, (you can find all about it in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summer_time_in_Europe#Table_of_transition_dates_for_European_Summer_Time), "European Summer Time begins (clocks go forward) at 01:00 UTC on the last Sunday in March, and ends (clocks go back) at 01:00 UTC on the last Sunday in October:", which actually was 2014-10-26. Now I'm wondering how `datetime` uses that when converting timestamps...

Comment: @ThierryLathuille I think the point here is that `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts)` returns local time if you don't specify the `tz` argument ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp)). My guess is the OP is in Europe (CET/CEST). The confusing thing is that this local time is naive nevertheless, i.e. it doesn't have the local time zone specified explicitly. But if you inspect closely, you'll find that the `fold` attribute is 1 for one of the datetime objects (the 2 am ones).

Comment: thanks, i foolishly didn't think about DST. That solves my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue revolves around [naive vs. aware datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#aware-and-naive-objects), and Python treating naive datetime as local time, i.e. the time zone your machine is configured to use. See also my comment under the question. To clarify a bit more, you can contrast the initial result to the ones you get if you set a time zone explicitly (essentially aware datetime).

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone
unix = [1414274400, 1414278000, 1414281600, 1414285200, 1414288800, 1414292400, 1414296000]
```

Initially: ***naive datetime*** (Unix time converted to local time). Note that the time zone of my machine is Europe/Berlin, which had a DST transition on 2014-10-26.

```
naive = [datetime.fromtimestamp(t) for t in unix]
print(list(map(datetime.isoformat, naive)))
# ['2014-10-26T00:00:00',
#  '2014-10-26T01:00:00',
#  '2014-10-26T02:00:00',
#  '2014-10-26T02:00:00',
#  '2014-10-26T03:00:00',
#  '2014-10-26T04:00:00',
#  '2014-10-26T05:00:00']
```

Notice the [fold attribute](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fold) of the datetime objects during the DST transition:

```
print(naive[2:4])
[datetime.datetime(2014, 10, 26, 2, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2014, 10, 26, 2, 0, fold=1)]
```

---

Now compare to ***aware datetime, localized to the machines time zone*** (my machine uses time zone Europe/Berlin, UTC offset +1/+2):

```
local_aware = [datetime.fromtimestamp(t).astimezone(None) for t in unix]
print(list(map(datetime.isoformat, local_aware)))
# ['2014-10-26T00:00:00+02:00',
#  '2014-10-26T01:00:00+02:00', # CEST (summer time)
#  '2014-10-26T02:00:00+02:00', # observe the DST transition!
#  '2014-10-26T02:00:00+01:00', # CET (winter time)
#  '2014-10-26T03:00:00+01:00',
#  '2014-10-26T04:00:00+01:00',
#  '2014-10-26T05:00:00+01:00']
```

The easiest thing you can do in my opinion is use ***UTC***:

```
utc = [datetime.fromtimestamp(t, timezone.utc) for t in unix]
print(list(map(datetime.isoformat, utc)))
# ['2014-10-25T22:00:00+00:00',
#  '2014-10-25T23:00:00+00:00',
#  '2014-10-26T00:00:00+00:00', # no DST transitions here of course
#  '2014-10-26T01:00:00+00:00',
#  '2014-10-26T02:00:00+00:00',
#  '2014-10-26T03:00:00+00:00',
#  '2014-10-26T04:00:00+00:00']
```

---

Regarding your first example of adding seconds etc. - here's how it can look like with UTC explicitly specified

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone

s = "2014-10-26 00:00:00" # UTC
# to aware datetime object, then Unix time
t = datetime.fromisoformat(s).replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc).timestamp()
# 1414281600.0

# add 1 day and back to datetime object / string
dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(t+86400, timezone.utc)
print(repr(dt))
# datetime.datetime(2014, 10, 27, 0, 0, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
print(dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
# 2014-10-27 00:00:00
```

Comment: thank you. I learned about the issue because of your suggestions and now have a clearer picture

Comment: @stdout I just noted that I didn't address your first example (the one with the seconds added) - let me add that as well.